# replace search & basket icon shopisle

Tags: css, wordpress, icons, themes

I tried to replace the basket icon in shopisle with a custom image (PNG). Mi problem is that it shows both icons the new and the original Icon. What did i forgot in my code to hide the original icon?

THX in advance
 Regards Jordi

```
/* search & basket icon */
.navbar-cart .glyphicon-search:before {
    color: #4CD9FF;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.navbar-cart span.icon-basket {
    color: #4CD9FF;
    font-size: 20px;
    content: '';
    background: url('your URL') no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basket icon is defined on the ::before anchor.

```
.icon-basket::before
```

And that's where you should manage to customize it.

```
.navbar-cart span.icon-basket::before {
    color: #4CD9FF;
    font-size: 20px;
    content: '';
    background: url('your URL') no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px
}
```

Comment: thanks gael. it nearly works, but now the font-size seems to be fixed and it dont change if i put 50px for example

Comment: Because for the font-size is without the ::before  .navbar-cart span.icon-basket {
    font-size: 30px;
}

Comment: sorry i`ll try my very best but i`m not a coder. so may be you can explain that for me how to change. because if i delete the before anchor  i see 2 basket icons.  thx

Comment: thanks for your help, but it does not work for me. with your updated code the cart icon disapears and only the counter is visible.

Comment: I rolled back to my previous reply because it seems I didn't understant your need. Now you are using a background image instead of the icon font, the font size won't resize you cart. You shall try to play on container width and height to resize it. Or post another question if still misunderstood...

Comment: no solution at this time,... i tried to play with padding and width and was able to resize the image. but it wasnt centered then. For the moment i just changed colors and icon size. thx anyway